# App not showing Push Notifications on the three possible app states

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging

I need to implement Cloud Messaging in my Flutter app.

For now the app can receive and show Push Notifications depending on the app status as follows:

App Status: Started and in foreground

Android: OK

iOS: not OK

App Status: Started and in background

Android: OK

iOS: OK

App Status: Closed

Android: not OK

iOS: OK

I will put here my current code for the app:

```
main.dart



///STREAM QUE CONTROLA LA RECEPCION DE MENSAJES CUANDO LA APP ESTA CERRADA O EN BACKGROUND
Future<void> backgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async{
  //INICIALIZAMOS FIREBASE
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  print(message.data.toString());
  print(message.notification!.title);
}

Future<void> main() async {
  //PERMITIR EL USO DE LIBRERIAS EXTERNAS QUE NECESITEN INTERACTUAR CON EL ARBOL DE WIDGETS
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  //INICIALIZACION DE EASYLOCALIZATION (TRADUCCION DE LA UI A EN, CA, ES)
  await EasyLocalization.ensureInitialized();

  //INICIALIZAMOS FIREBASE
  await Firebase.initializeApp();



  //INICIALIZAMOS EL STREAM PARA PODER RECIBIR MENSAJES CUANDO LA APP ESTE CERRADA O EN BACKGROUND
  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(backgroundHandler);

  DarkThemeProvider themeChangeProvider = DarkThemeProvider();






  runApp(EasyLocalization(
      path: "idiomas",
      fallbackLocale: Locale("es", "ES"),
      saveLocale: true,
      supportedLocales: [
        Locale("en", "EN"),
        Locale("es", "ES"),
        Locale("ca", "CA")
      ],

      child: MultiProvider(
        providers: [
          ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) {
            return themeChangeProvider;
          }),
          ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => UsuarioProvider()),
          ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => EmpresaProvider()),
          ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => ApplicationBloc())
        ],

        child: Consumer<DarkThemeProvider>(builder: (context, themeData, child) {
          return MaterialApp(
              theme: Styles.themeData(themeChangeProvider.darkTheme, context),
              routes: {
                "noticias": (_) => MyHomePage(currentIndex: 0,),
                "avisos": (_) => MyHomePage(currentIndex: 1,),
                "tareas": (_) => MyHomePage(currentIndex: 2,),
                "perfil": (_) => MyHomePage(currentIndex: 3,),
              },
              home: MyApp());
        }),
      )));
}



class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {



  String? token = " ";


  DarkThemeProvider themeChangeProvider = DarkThemeProvider();

  void getCurrentAppTheme() async {
    themeChangeProvider.darkTheme =
        await themeChangeProvider.darkThemePreferences.getTheme();
  }
  Future<void>_init() async{

    if(Platform.isIOS){
      final settings  = await FirebaseMessaging.instance.requestPermission();
      if(settings.authorizationStatus == AuthorizationStatus.authorized){}
    }
    else
      {}


  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    getCurrentAppTheme();

    super.initState();

    //COMPROBAMOS LA PLATAFORMA
    if(Platform.isIOS){
      //SOLICITAMOS PERMISOS A IOS PARA RECIBIR PUSH
      _init();

    }



    //INICIALIZAMOS LOCAL NOTIFICATION SERVICE

    LocalNotificationService.initialize(context);

    //DEJAMOS PREPARADA LA APP PARA RECIBIR UNA PUSH Y ABRIRLA EN EK CASO DE QUE LA APP ESTE CERRADA
    FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage().then((message) {
      if(message != null){
        final routeFromMessage = message.data["route"];

        Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(routeFromMessage);
      }
    });

    ///CON LA APP ACTIVA SE EJECUTA ESTA STREAM PARA OBTENER LOS DATOS DE LA PUSH
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((message) {

      if(message.notification != null){
        print(message.notification!.body);
        print(message.notification!.title);
      }

    LocalNotificationService.display(message);
    });

    ///CON LA APP ABIERTA PERO EN SEGUNDO PLANO Y EL USUARIO HACE CLICK
    ///SOBRE LA PUSH, LA APP SE REABRE ABRIENDO LA PANTALLA INDICADA EN ROUTES
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((message) {
      final routeFromMessage = message.data["route"];
      print("ruta recibida en la push ${routeFromMessage}");

      Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(routeFromMessage);
    });


  }








  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return
            Consumer<DarkThemeProvider>(builder: (context, themeData, child) {
          return MaterialApp(
            localizationsDelegates: context.localizationDelegates,
            supportedLocales: context.supportedLocales,
            locale: context.locale,
            title: 'Evan.zero',
            theme: Styles.themeData(themeChangeProvider.darkTheme, context),
            home: MyHomePage(currentIndex: 0,),

          );
        });
  }
}



local_notification_service.dart

class LocalNotificationService {
  static final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin _notificationsPlugin =
      FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

  static void initialize(BuildContext context) {
    final InitializationSettings initializationSettings =
        InitializationSettings(
            android: AndroidInitializationSettings("@drawable/ic_stat_zf"));

    _notificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings,onSelectNotification: (String? route) async{
      if(route != null){
        Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(route);
      }
    });
  }

  static void display(RemoteMessage message) async {

    try {
      final id = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch ~/1000;

      const NotificationDetails notificationDetails = const NotificationDetails(
        android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
          "evanzero",
          "evanzero channel",
          importance: Importance.max,
          priority: Priority.high,
        )
      );


      await _notificationsPlugin.show(
        id,
        message.notification!.title,
        message.notification!.body,
        notificationDetails,
        payload: message.data["route"],
      );
    } on Exception catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
}
```

I am asking you to check the code and tell me what should I add or remove to receive Push Notifications on both platforms and on the three possible states

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android closed app and in foreground and background my working example:

```
    @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    var initializationSettingsAndroid = new AndroidInitializationSettings('app_icon');

    var initializationSettingsIOS = new IOSInitializationSettings();

    var initializationSettings = new InitializationSettings(android: initializationSettingsAndroid, iOS: initializationSettingsIOS);

    flutterNotificationPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

    flutterNotificationPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings, onSelectNotification : onNotificationInForegroundPressed);

    FirebaseMessaging.instance
        .getInitialMessage()
        .then((RemoteMessage? message) {
      if (message != null) {
        Beamer.of(context).beamToNamed(
            '/myroot/${message.data["id"].toString()}/myroot2');
        notifications.setNotificationOpened(message.data["id"]);
      }
    });

    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen(
          (RemoteMessage message) async {
        RemoteNotification? notification = message.notification;
        AndroidNotification? android = message.notification?.android;

        notifications.setNotificationReceived(message.data['id'].toString());
        var requestId = message.data['requestId'].toString();
        var messageId = message.data['messageId'].toString();
        FCMPayload fcmPayload = FCMPayload(id: '$id', messageId : '$messageId');
        String fcmPayloadJsonString = fcmPayload.toJsonString();

        if (notification != null && android != null && !kIsWeb) {
          flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
            notification.hashCode,
            notification.title,
            notification.body.toString(),
            NotificationDetails(
              android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
                channel.id,
                channel.name,
                icon: 'launch_background',
              ),
            ),
              payload: fcmPayloadJsonString
          );
        }
      },
    );

    FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
      Beamer.of(context).beamToNamed(
          '/myroot/${message.data["id"].toString()}/myroot2');
      notifications.setNotificationOpened(message.data["messageId"]);
    });
  }

  void Function()? onNotificationInForegroundPressed(String? payload)  {
    FCMPayload fcmpayload = FCMPayload.fromJsonString(payload!);
    Beamer.of(context).beamToNamed(
        '/myroot/${fcmpayload.requestId}/myroot');
    notifications.setNotificationOpened(fcmpayload.messageId);
  }
```